# How to replace a number with another number in Tableau?

Tags: database, tableau-api, visualization

I have a column in my worksheet in Tableau that has a value like 102%. I need to replace it with 100%. How can I do that? I already tried the following in calculated field.
`IF [x]>1 THEN [x]=1 ELSE [x] END`

It gives me this error: Expected type boolean, found Float. Result types from IF expressions must match. How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the [x]= and just put 1.

```
IF [x]>1 THEN 1 ELSE [x] END
```

If that doesn't work, look into converting the field to a string and converting it back to a FLOAT with something like the below:

```
FLOAT(IF LEFT(STR([x]),1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE STR([x]) END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "IF [x]>1 THEN 1 ELSE [x] END" This fixed the error, however, the outputs are 0 and 1s. And it does not show the original values

Comment: You may need to check the formatting on it. Make sure it's formatted to percentages. If that doesn't fix it, let me know and we can troubleshoot more.